# Image generation using different images of own

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, image-generation

I am creating an AI room decorator and for that I have different image which I have to compile the images and make a single image out of it
Example I have one picture of Bed table and Tv in PNG form and i have to compile these image one a single image and make a room having these things

So what should i use for making it?
please suggest any API or coding for it

I am a beginner in college so please suggest a bit easy method and if you not able to understand please let me know